# Application crashes on dialog dismiss

Tags: android

I know there are number of solutions given for this question, but none of them worked for me. Even after having all of the checks, my application crashes on dismiss dialog.

Here is the code I am using :

```
public void dismissDialog(int dialogId) {
    Dialog dialog = getDialog(dialogId);
    Activity activity = mActivity.get();
    if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            mDialogsMap.remove(dialogId);
        }
    }
}
```

I am dismissing all the dialog using this method but still users are getting these crashes.

See logs :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{144f7eb V.E...... R......D 0,0-684,240} not attached to window manager
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
       at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:362)
       at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:345)
       at com.syntonic.freeway.android.DialogController.dismissDialog(SourceFile:64)
       at com.syntonic.freeway.android.ui.OffersAndRewardDetailActivity$4.onSuccess(SourceFile:770)
       at com.gs.jutil.web.NetworkCallback.onProgress(SourceFile:64)
       at com.gs.jutil.web.NetworkCallback.validate(SourceFile:7)
       at com.gs.jutil.web.NetworkCallback$1.run(SourceFile:46)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `dismissDialog()` and which line is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is because that the dialog is closed after the view has been destroyed... Try this

```
if (view.isShown()) {
dialog.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're trying to close a dialog that isn't attached.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{144f7eb V.E...... R......D 0,0-684,240} not attached to window manager
```

Instead of passing around dialogId's, you should pass the dialog objects around. Are you storing a hashmap or list of dialogs that are open and trying to close them iteratively? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you're passing the dialogs around, you can at least guarantee that they're attached, or at least check that they're still attached.

Here's an example of how I've managed clicks inside fragments
 https://github.com/jmitchell38488/android-todo-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/jmitchell38488/todo/app/ui/activity/ListActivity.java

```
List<DialogFragment> dialogs = new ArrayList<>();
dialogs.add(myNewDialog);
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    if (some_code_that_does_not_dismiss) {
        dialog.remove(dialog);
        ...
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

edit based on feedback:
If you're storing weak references (which I think is wrong - just how many dialogs can you have open at any time or stored in memory?), then you need to use a `DialogManager` to manage them, as well as a `DialogFactory` to instantiate them, on top of which, you need an abstract class that extends `DialogFragment` so that you can centralise your dismiss and management logic. That way all you need to do is:

```
DialogFactory.getInstance(/** args **/)
```

Then inside onStop or onDestroy:

```
// If you want to store them in the bundle
SerializedDialogManager = DialogManager.serialize();

// Else, delete them
DialogManager.shutdown();
```

Inside your shutdown, you check each dialog to see if it still exists and can be dismissed:

```
List<Integer> dialogIds = new ArrayList<>();
for (int id ; dialogIds) {
    Dialog d = getDialog(id);
    if (d != null && d.isShown()) {
        d.dismiss();
    }
}
```

But really, you should be handling your dismiss actions inside the dialogs.

Food for thought, but I personally think that you shouldn't bother too much with weak references and let the activities/dialogs deal with instantiation and shut down.

Comment: Actually I am maintaining a weak reference of dialog because I am handlling all the dialogs in my application from single place .  I call dismissDialog on the response of certain callbacks and they are async calls so sometimes it get crashed.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your valuable time and suggestion But it requires lots of change in my present code as application is very complex and is in very stable condition,  which took lots of efforts;) so I cant take risk as there is more than 100 dialogs. So by looking my present method any change that you can suggest?

Comment: Just add a null check  to your current code and check if it is shown `if (dialog != null && dialog.isShown()) { dialog.dismiss(); }`